# A basic for loop, too messy? And where should i go from here next?

Tags: javascript, optimization

So i have coded this little for loop which creates the binary version of the decimal numbers in the range of 0-255. I wanted it to make a line break after every iteration.

As a beginner, which little tips could i use to write this for loop in a more clean and precise way?

```
for(i=0;i<=255;i++){

   console.log(i+":"+i.toString(2)) //usually commented out
   var x = document.createElement("br") //creating a <br> html element 
   var y = document.getElementById("body") // reference to the html body
   y.appendChild(x) //appending the <br> to the html body
   document.write(i+": "+i.toString(2) + " ") //writing to the document

}
```

- I already have found out that i shouldn't use document.write()
- I referenced the body of the document, would it be better to create an dedicated div for the output?
- I guess i could do the calculation from dec to bin outside document.write(), 
  would that be better?

I hope you can help me with some useful insight, and please don't explain it in detail - i love me some hints/riddles:-) Thank you, and greetings!

Comment: To know where you should go, you need to decide where exactly you need to come. Expected output would be a nice addition to your post.

Comment: so createElement and set the text append the element.

Comment: There's no need to get the body 255 times, you could create a variable outside the loop and reference it there. Also, I wouldn't create 255 <br />, instead I would create a container for all of them and wrap each number in a span. Then I'd style the spans to go on a new line each time, but that's just personal preference

Comment: This is probably a better place for questions that have no real, specific problem, but are looking for "improvement": https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you, i'll go there in future as i have a lot of code review questions! thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your code cleaner, avoid `document.write()` and also not trigger redrawing every time you append an element to the DOM, you can put your markup into a variable and then set the `innerHTML` of the body (or any other element you want the list being output to), resulting in only one page redraw.

```js
var markup = '';

for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
  markup += i + ": " + i.toString(2) + "<br>";
}

document.body.innerHTML = markup;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! wow, that is precise code:-)i guess markup is the global empty variable outside the for loop which is filled with the output. and then you set the document's body.innerHtml to the markup variable to print out the output in one go so to speak?

Comment: Exactly. The browser will update the DOM by converting the markup to actual DOM elements as children of the element and then trigger a refresh in the rendering engine, as opposed to triggering a refreh every time a new child DOM node is added. Actually, modern browsers have means to optimize that and will try to not redraw on every node that is added, but you shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to string concatenation is using a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment):

> ...because the document fragment isn't part of the active document tree structure, changes made to the fragment don't affect the document, cause reflow, or incur any performance impact that can occur when changes are made.

```js
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (let i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
  const para = document.createElement('p');
  para.textContent = i + ": " + i.toString(2);
  fragment.appendChild(para);
}

document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: mhm interesting, so a fragment is sort of like a variable with little effect to the document? thank you.